# Android MediaPlayer: Get HTTP response headers

Tags: android, authentication, http-headers, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a VideoView that gets a video from an authenticated source, so I've added headers to the request using setVideoURI(Uri uri, Map headers), which seems related to [this MediaPlayer setDataSource method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)). This works fine.

However, I need to get the response headers returned from the servers because the authentication information refreshes with each request. Where can I get the Response?  I assume it has to do with setting some kind of listener?

I've really exhausted the Internet on this one.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Getting HTTP response headers is not support in the clean way on media player.
The author of this class implement it in native not in java.

```
    private native void nativeSetDataSource(
    IBinder httpServiceBinder, String path, String[] keys, String[] values)
    throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I'd upvote you but apparently I need more SO cred.  Let me see if I understand correctly.  When you say "clean way", what do you mean?  What does implementing in native mean?  That looks like Java, no?